# How do I make a fragment's onActivityCreated method run again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have one Activity that instanciates some fragments:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, HomeFragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, BorrowedFragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LentFragment.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, PeopleFragment.class.getName()));
```

Those fragments are linked to a ViewPager. Each fragment runs a SELECT statement and shows the contents as a list to the user.

The problem is that in the HomeFragment, I have a button that when clicked, it shows to the user a Form, so he can add information to this Table. When user adds the information, I finish() the activity and the HomeFragment is shown  again.
When I swype to the BorrowFragment nothing is shown there. I have to swype to PeopleFragment (the last one of the list) and come back to BorrowedFragment. Only then, the information is shown.

The only thing I do at the moment when the information is inserted is:

```
Button btDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
        btDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ck1.isChecked())
                    isIOwe = true;
                else
                    isIOwe = false;
                insertRecord();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(Fragment.instantiate(ctx, PeopleFragment.class.getName()), "test");
                ft.commit();*/
                finish();

            }
        });
```

I've been wondering if there's something I should do with the FragmentTransaction, to be able to restart the lifecyle of the fragments.

Any help?

Thanks,
Felipe

Answer (score 0):

I think executing your query in the getView method of the fragment should do the trick.

If not, there is an other possibility. I do not know the ViewPager very good, but I wouldn't be surprised if it has a listener that will be called when one of its fragments is shown. If you let your fragments implement a interface which let its descendants implement an executeQuery method you could just loop through your list of fragments and call that when the event occurs.

Comment: Hey Bram. I tried having the code at the getView, but didn't work. Also, I couldn't find any listener for the ViewPager that could help me achieve this, unfortunately! Thanks for the help